# Abstract class with equals method for all subclasses

Tags: java

I am trying to override the equals method in an abstract class. Is there a way that I can check if the parameter `Object o` is an instance of the class that has inherited the method and to then typecast o to same type as the class that has inherited the equals method?

This is what I have tried so far, but I am receiving the error variable of type `java.lang.Object`. Is there a reason that o is not being typecast?  The `getOperand()`
 method returns a compound type.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o.getClass() == this.getClass()){
        this.getClass().cast(o);
        return (o.getOperand().equals(this.getOperand()));
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but I can't get it to work" -> why not? Is there a compile error? A runtime exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please clarify. Also, you may want to take a lookat [`Class#isAssignableFrom(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) since it takes care of inheritance as well.

Comment: What does `getOperand()` return? I am guessting a `String`. Use `o.getOperand().equals(this.getOperand())` instead?

Comment: "The getOperand() method returns a compound type." -> As @CKing mentioned, unless this is a singleton, you sould not compare them with `==`. In fact, [you should never compare any object with `==` unless you know exactly what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to :

1. Assign the result of the cast to your class reference type so that the compiler is able to find the `getOperand` method since `Object` class doesn't have such a method.
2. Use the `equals` method to compare the `operand` values rather than using `==`.
3. Use `instanceof` so that the solution supports mixed type equality. (Read [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Optional if you don't want to support mixed type equality)
4. Mark the `equals` method as `final` to prevent subclasses from overriding it inorder to support symmetry (if `x.equals(y)` then `y.equals(x)`. Not required if not supporting mixed type equality)

   ```
   public abstract class EqualsTest {
       public final boolean equals(Object o) {//make equals final to maintain symmetry
           if (o instanceof EqualsTest) {//use instanceof
               EqualsTest e = (EqualsTest)o;//cast and assign to EqualTest reference
               return e.getOperand().equals(this.getOperand());//use equals here
           } else
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

With the above changes, sub-classes can inherit the equals method as is :

```
class EqualsTestSubClass extends EqualsTest {
      //inherts the equals and getOperand methods.      
}

class EqualsTestSubClass2 extends EqualsTestSubClass {
      //inherts the equals and getOperand methods.      
}
```

You can then check equality of an `EqualsTestSubClass` instance which is a direct subclass of `EqualsTest` and `EqualsTestSubClass2` instance which is a subclass of  `EqualsTestSubClass` instances as follows :

```
EqualsTest e1 = new EqualsTestSubClass();
EqualsTest e2 = new EqualsTestSubClass2();
System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));
```

**Note** : It is a better idea to directly compare the `operand` field in the `equals` method rather than using `getOperand` since `getOperand` is overridable.

Comment: The equals() method is in an abstract class and I can't create an instance of it the same way you declared EqualsTest e. Is there a way to generically typecast a variable to the same type as the class that will inherit the abstract method?  I intend on having four classes inherit the abstract class.

Comment: @JohnRolding `EqualsTest` being `abstract` wouldn't affect the answer. You are not creating an instance of `EqualTest` in the `equals` method. You are just casting the value passed to the `equals` method in `EqualTest` and assigning it to an `EqualTest` reference.